# Issue related to a console application in C#/NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I have the following code in a C# console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello...");
    }
}
```

When I run this application, the command prompt appears and suddenly disappear, but I have seen at my friend's house when I run the application, the command prompt asks to `Press any key to Continue`. When I press any key after then the application terminates.., but in my PC it doesn't work without writing `Consol.ReadLine()`.

Is there a setting to get the user to the `Press Any Key to Continue` line?

Comment: Its because your program exits after completion

Answer (score 5):

Sadly no, but if you *Debug->Start Without Debugging* <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> it will make that effect.

Clearly you could add

```
Console.Write("\nPress Any Key to Continue");
Console.Readkey();
```

at the end of your program.

If you want to be (nearly) sure that your code will always show that prompt:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.Write("\nPress Any Key to Continue");
    Console.ReadKey();
};
```

Put these lines at the beginning of your `Main()` method.

But I think this is a little overboard :-) It installs an exit handler that will ask for a key on exit.

Now, if you want to really really go overboard and show, you can go up to eleven:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.Write("\nPress Any Key to Continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    };
}
```

This will ask for the key only if the debugger is attached (even these lines have to be put at the beginning of the `Main()` method. They replace the other versions). With `Start Without Debugging` the debugger **isn't** attached, so Visual Studio will show its prompt instead of yours.

(Instead of using the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`, you could have protected the whole Main() with a `try...finally` block, and in the finally put the `Console.*`, but that wasn't funny :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Disappearing **is** the correct behaviour. If you want it to appear this way just add
`Console.ReadKey();` Of course you can add some message before ("Press any key...") etc.